# .NET assemblies memory usage

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly

Suppose I have two total separate .NET apps, `Foo.exe` and `Boo.exe`, both of which are using the same library `TestLib.dll` which is located in the bin folder of Foo and Boo (two copies).

Will .NET load both of these dlls, wasting `size_of_dll * 2` size of RAM or it will check strong assemblies names, sizes etc... and load and load only one of the two assemblies?

Comment: In short - yes. look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374224(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I don't know, if windows does not do it (e.g. for its own signed assemblies), but it would be **insane** to do such a thing. Even when you have the same name, version and size, you still can have bitwise difference between two assemblies got from different sources, providers or regions (or patched assemblies).

Comment: The size of assembly is nothing compared to how much memory could be allocated by the program at runtime (up to 8Tb).

Comment: No.. our program have assemblies total size >  400 Mb and most of them now are used in different aps.. so user will waste a lot of RAM! 4aps * 300 Mb

Comment: just for example how we waste RAM

Comment: @BransDs I implemented the solution u deleted just now, but its working as intended. Its not going in if condition. What was that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that a feature of DLLs is that multiple processes both using that DLL can share certain sections in order to reduce memory usage (this is a Windows feature and is not specific to .Net), however I'm fairly certain that for this to work the two processes must load the same physical DLL on disk, in which case this won't be happening for the scenario you describe.

If you instead installed into a common location (e.g. the GAC) then Windows would be able to share certain portions of the DLL across multiple processes in order to save memory.  In the case of .net assemblies you also need to [NGen the assembly in order to take advantage of this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163610.aspx)

Note that the amount of memory "saved" is **not** `size_of_dll` as certain parts of that DLL image cannot be shared, namely any section of that DLL which may be modified.  These sections are still duplicated across multiple processes to ensure that applications don't accidentally modify each others data.

Comment: `If you instead installed into a common location (e.g. the GAC) then Windows would be able to share certain portions of the DLL across multiple processes in order to save memory.` Really? In addition being in GAC, i think they may have to be pre-jit (ngen) as well ?

Comment: @YK1 Yeah, looks like that is the case

Comment: I think just Ngen is enough - but if assembly is in GAC then its more performant. GAC is not mandatory. Anyway, I up-vote your answer because it is more complete than mine. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the DLL will be loaded once per AppDomain. However you you can share the DLL's across multiple AppDomain's to reduce the memory usage. As described in this [code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6578/Use-AppDomains-To-Reduce-Memory-Consumption-in-NET).

> If an assembly is used by multiple domains in a process, the
>   assembly's code (but not its data) can be shared by all domains
>   referencing the assembly. This reduces the amount of memory used at
>   run time.

Comment: I don't think `AppDomains` can be shared. You can marshal variables across `AppDomain` boundaries but I haven't come across a way to "share" `AppDomains` between processes.

Comment: No but you can share the DLL's across multiple app domains.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "share the DLL's". Regardless, the question is about whether two *separate* processes will use the same assembly or not. Not about `AppDomains`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want multiple processes to share the same assembly, you have two options:

1. You could put the assembly in the `GAC` or `Global Assembly Cache`. You can do this by using [GacUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).
2. You can use a config file and the [codeBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb%28vs.80%29.aspx) element to share a privately deployed assembly among a small group of applications.

Comment: Thank you. I know... And not only put in GAC but i can use AssemblyResolve event to use the same assembly in different processes... but i begin doubting. maybe .NET checks all assemblies, and reduce memory usage and load time by sharing the same assemblies from different locations outside GAC ..

Comment: See my latest edit, you can even share privately deployed assemblies!

Answer (score 2):

Tested this with two .net 4.0 projects, one class library and Process Explorer - by default Visual Studio copies referenced dlls to projects' `bin` directory.

Process Explorer returns two different addresses for the referenced dll, while the same address for other, windows-specific libraries.

Conclusion: Yes, for two copies of the same library in different folders, loaded by two applications, the same library may be loaded twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking whether the code of the assembly is loaded once per process or shared between processes like native dlls. Answer is no mainly because the code is not native and it has to be JIT. Jitting happens per process. Pre-jitted assemblies (ngen) are able to share code.